# Google Cloud Platform: ssh from VM_1 in project_A to VM_2 in project_B

Tags: ssh, debian, virtual-machine, google-cloud-platform, ssh-keys

I am trying to connect virtual machine VM_1 in  project_A to  virtual machine VM_2 in project_B. Bot are on Debian Linux.

Steps I did:

On VM_1 Project_A

Generated private and public keys

1. ssh-keygen -t rsa -f ~/.ssh/my-ssh-key -C example-user
2. $ chmod 400 ~/.ssh/my-ssh-key

In a browser,  Metadata page of project_B.

1. Clicked SSH Keys to show a list of project-wide public SSH keys and added public keys that I created from VM_1 Project_A

Now the keys are added I tried ssh from virtual machine VM_1 on Project_A to Vm_2 on Project_B

it is giving error

> Permission denied (publickey)

Please advise

Answer (score 0):

It seems a bug that I can not apply public key to a particular VM in a project. I was able to connect it by applying public ssh key to whole project.